# Como usar typeahead em vários campos ao mesmo tempo?

Tags: javascript, jquery, typeahead

Olá, queria saber como eu posso estar usando o `typeahead` em vários inputs.

Estou usando *Bootstrap* e com ele fiz um `row` com alguns inputs, no primeiro input estou usando `typeahead` para buscar palavras, há possibilidade de clonar esse `row` fazendo assim novas entradas.

O problema é, o `typeahead` só funciona no primeiro input, nos demais ele não funciona.

---

```
<input type="text" name="palavras" class="form-control typeahead" data-provide="typeahead">

var substringMatcher = function (strs) {
   return function findMatches(q, cb) {
      var matches, substrRegex;
      matches = [];
      substrRegex = new RegExp(q, 'i');
      $.each(strs, function (i, str) {
         if (substrRegex.test(str)) {
            matches.push(str);
         }
      });
      cb(matches);
   };
};

var palavras= ['olá', 'tudo bem', 'sol', 'praia','neve'];

$('.typeahead').typeahead({
   hint: true,
   highlight: true,
   minLength: 1
},{
  name: 'palavras',
  source: substringMatcher(palavras)
});
```

Espero abrir uma discussão legal sobre este tema.

Comment: Adicione seu código para entendermos melhor o seu problema.